# How can I add a CNAME file to the root of the master?

Tags: github, pelican

I am using Pelican to generate a GitHub page. This page has a custom domain. To make the custom domain work, I need a file called `CNAME` in the master branch.

However, when I execute `make github` it doesn't copy the `CNAME` file.

How can I make pelican copy the `CNAME` file to the root of the output?

### What I've tried

See https://github.com/ML-KA/ML-KA.github.io/ for the GitHub repository. I use Pelican 3.5.0.

I have `CNAME` in the root of the source directory as well as in a directory `extra/`

I've added the following lines to `pelicanconf.py`:

```
STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'extra']
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {'extra/CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'}, }
```

I've also tried to add the following lines instead to `pelicanconf.py`:

```
STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'extra/CNAME']
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {'extra/CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'}, }
```

And I've tried to add them additionally to `publishconf.py`. All variants seem to have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths and files defined by `STATIC_PATHS` should be inside the content folder. So, put your `extra` folder inside `content`.

Answer (score -1):

Your second example should work:

```
STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'extra/CNAME']
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {'extra/CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'}, }
```

That's how I defined it in my blog as well (see https://github.com/DirkR/niebegeg.net/blob/master/pelicanconf.py#L82).

`publishconf.py` is just a wrapper around `pelicanconf.py` to set some deployment options (`SITE_URL`, etc.) for the live site instead of the test setup.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Obviously, you can't say what is going wrong. Telling the approach which I was using, but which doesn't work, should work doesn't help.